# How to customize a onclick event listener to seek to a time in video or change the source

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, interactive, featherlight.js

Trying to fork a tutorial file. 
Please help.

The tutorial has the objective of creating a `featherlight` pop up at a certain time during the video play back.
That pop up has 2 options, based on what the user clicks on, the play head seeks to a particular time on the video; essentially creating an interactive video.

There are 2 other boxes which give additional information about the people in the video, these are done with absolute/relative floating divs that hover over a specified point in the video. I just want to fork it in a way where if the `featherlight` popup which is a separate entity than the box1/box2 floating divs is gone and it's functionality is directly built into the box1/box2 divs where the user can click on the choice provided and the playhead would seek to that time option. (in the tut code it is at 7 sec & 20 sec mark)

the html part :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Interactive Video</title>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <!-- jQuery -->
 <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Skeleton CSS & Featherlight -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/featherlight.css">
 <script src="js/featherlight.js"></script>

 <!-- Interaction CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/interaction.css">

 <!-- Interaction js -->
 <script src="js/interaction.js"></script>

 <!-- GreenSock -->
 <script src="js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row videoArea">
   <div class="box1"></div>
   <div class="box2"></div>
   <video id="video1" controls autoplay="true">
    <source src="media/office_conv.m4v" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>
  </div>

  <div class="row descArea">
   
   <h5>Video Title</h5>
   <p>This is the description</p>
   <div class="current">0:00</div>
   <div class="duration">0:00</div>

  </div>

 </div> <!-- End of Container -->

 <div class="lightbox popUpQuestion1">
  <h4>Question 1</h4>
  <p>Think about what you learned and then how would you respond?</p>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="button longBtns goodChoice">Calmly respond with helpful info</a>
  <a href="#" class="button longBtns badChoice">Why is he asking me this question?</a>
 </div>

 <div class="lightbox persona1PopUp">
  <img src="images/Justin.jpg">
  <h5>Justins Hanks</h5>
  <p>Role: Development Manager</p>
  <p>Bio: Justin has been a manager for 4 years. sakjdhsakjdh askjdh ksajhd aksjh askjdhksajd askjhd askjhdkjsah </p>
  <p>Previous Experiences</p>
  <ul>
   <li>Experience 1: 2002-2004</li>
   <li>Experience 2: 2005-2009</li>
   <li>Experience 3: 2010-2016</li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="lightbox persona2PopUp">
  <img src="images/Matt.jpg">
  <h5>Matt Briscoe</h5>
  <p>Role: Developer</p>
  <p>Bio: Matt has been a manager for 4 years. This alkjdlas asldkjasldj aslkdj aklsdjlsakdjalskjd salkdj salkjd</p>
  <p>Previous Experiences</p>
  <ul>
   <li>Experience 1: 2002-2004</li>
   <li>Experience 2: 2005-2009</li>
   <li>Experience 3: 2010-2016</li>
  </ul>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The Interactive JS part :

```js
// Various variables
var videoHalfWay = 0;
var formattedHalfWay = 0;

// Choice parts
var choicePart = 7;
var goodChoicePart = 7;
var badChoicePart = 20;
var goodChoiceChosen = false;

// Question variable
var question1Asked = false;

var video1;

$(document).ready(function(){

 $.featherlight.defaults.afterClose = playPauseVideo;

 video1 = $('#video1');
 
 $('.box1').on('click', function(){
  playPauseVideo('.persona1PopUp');
 });

 $('.box2').on('click', function(){
  playPauseVideo('.persona2PopUp');
 });

 $('.goodChoice').on('click', function(){
  goodChoiceChosen = true;
  $.featherlight.close();
  video1[0].currentTime = goodChoicePart;
 })

 $('.badChoice').on('click', function(){
  $.featherlight.close();
  video1[0].currentTime = badChoicePart;
 })

 $(video1).on('loadeddata', function(){
  videoHalfWay = Math.round(this.duration/2);
 })

 $(video1).on('timeupdate', function(){
  var currentTime = Math.round(this.currentTime);
  var durationNum = Math.round(this.duration);
  var formattedCurrentTime = secondsToHms(currentTime);
  var formattedDurationTime = secondsToHms(durationNum)
  onTrackedVideoFram(formattedCurrentTime, formattedDurationTime)
  
  if(currentTime == choicePart && question1Asked == false){
   question1Asked = true;
   video1[0].pause();
   $.featherlight($('.popUpQuestion1'))
  }

  if(currentTime == badChoicePart && goodChoiceChosen == true){
   video1[0].pause();
  }

  if(currentTime == videoHalfWay){
   // Halfway point
  }

  if(currentTime == durationNum){
   // Video complete
  }

 });

});

function onTrackedVideoFram(curretTime, duration){
 $('.current').text(curretTime);
 $('.duration').text(duration);
}

function secondsToHms(d) {
 d = Number(d);
 var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
 var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
 var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);
 return ((h > 0 ? h + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" : "") : "") + m + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s); 
}

function playPauseVideo(popUp){
 if(video1[0].paused){
  video1[0].play();
 } else{
  video1[0].pause();
  $.featherlight($(popUp));
 }
}
```

What I want to do is, add the functionality of the `goodChoice` and `badChoice` directly by replacing the `personapopup1`.

I tried to use :

```js
$('.box1').on('click', function()
  { playPauseVideo('popUpQuestion1');
    )    $.featherlight.close();    }
```

But obviously that didn't work, could someone guide me?

Comment: The first obvious thing is the misplaced closing parenthesis... It should be after the closing curly bracket. -- Do you have errors in console?

Comment: Yes there are many, I am trying to knock out each one of them one by one?? could you maybe help me ?

Comment: Post the error list ;)

Comment: The main error is not even on the error. When I fork it, which I have deleted already as I needed to get the vanilla code so I can post here. 
The MAIN error was if I called the popupquestion after the playpause, the popup came, but when I click on an option it takes me to the 7 sec mark and the popup comes again. And only then when I click an option it goes away..

Comment: So I deleted the If loop that started the popupquestion at 7 sec & 20 sec mark. 
That solved a part of the problem, but I have some other queries, could you come on Skype & maybe spare a few minutes?

Comment: I created a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BdQbOW?editors=1111) with your code... (I changed the timecodes for 4 and 9, since my test video is too short) That is a cool feature! Now, I notice that the question popup isn't showing after one answer... I suppose that is the problem.

Comment: Indeed, could you help me a bit more by clearing some more of my doubts in this tutorial project? I will share the entire tutorial download link so you can fork it in your own way.

Comment: My website link is in my profile, you will find a Skype call link in the footer.